# Temporarily relationship in communication

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is the relationship that two people form when they are communicating called? Let's imagine that you meet someone on the street and have a brief chat. What is that synergy called?

Comment: I am not sure it's a relationship (which may require longer time to develop). Your example seems more like an *interaction*.

Comment: @alexsms, _interaction_ is "communication or direct involvement with someone or something". What I am looking for is the relationship one builds in that brief encounter. These relationships can also be built over time and many different interactions.

Answer (score 1):

To emphasize the unexpected and relatively short aspects of such a meeting would be that you *"encountered"* somebody.

> [[Merriam-Webster]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/encounter)
>   **encounter**
>   *transitive verb*
>   : "to come upon or experience especially unexpectedly"
>
> *intransitive verb*
>   : "to meet especially by chance"

Comment: so 'encounter' as a NOUN fits.